# Existence of a critical point between two local minimum

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

I would like some input in my attempted proof for this question:

> Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and has at least two local minima. Show that $f$ has a critical point between these two minima.

$\textbf{My answer:}$

Let $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ be local minima of $f$. Without loss of generality, assume $x_{1} \lt x_{2}$. If $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$, it is trivial from the Mean Value Theorem that $\exists c \in (x_{1},x_{2}): f'(c)=0$.

Suppose $f(x_{1}) \lt f(x_{2})$ [the case where $f(x_{1}) \gt f(x_{2})$ envolves the same steps]. By the Mean Value Theorem, $\exists c \in (x_{1},x_{2}): f'(c) \gt 0$.

Since $x_{2}$ is a local minimum, $\exists \delta_{2} \gt 0:y \in (x_{2}-\delta_{2},x_{2}+\delta_{2}) \implies f(y) \geq f(x_{2})$.

Consider the closed interval $[x_{2}-\delta_{2},x_{2}]$. By the Mean Value Theorem, $\exists m \in (x_{2}-\delta_{2},x_{2}):f'(m)=\frac{f(x_{2})-f(x_{2}-\delta_{2})}{\delta_{2}} \lt 0$.

Since $f$ is smooth, $f'$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, we have $c,m \in (x_{1},x_{2})$ and $f'(c) \gt 0$ and $f'(m) \lt 0$, hence, $\exists z \in (c,m):f'(z)=0$.

Comment: There is a maximum in $[x_1,x_2]$ since $f$ is continuous. The derivative there is zero, by Fermat's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function is **smooth** we can use the first derivative as a continuous function. So, if $x_1<x_2$ are the two points of **local** minimum, we can say that, for $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 >0$ such that $x_1+\epsilon_2<x_2-\epsilon_2$ we have:
$$
f'(x_1+\epsilon_1)>0 \quad \mbox{and}\quad f'(x_2-\epsilon_2)<0
$$
so, since $f'(x)$ is continuous there is a point $x_3$ in $[x_1+\epsilon_1,x_2-\epsilon_2]$ such that $f'(x_3)=0$

This seems essentially your idea, without the use of $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.

Comment: You both used the continuity of the derivative, which is not necessary to be used.

Comment: The OP says that the function is smooth, and using this fact we have a ''simpler'' proof. But, yes, the proof in OP is more general. But note that, without conditions on the continuity of the derivative, we can have  local minima ( and maxima ) in points where the function is not differentiable, and this can gives some problem.

Comment: One can have existence of the derivative without the derivative being continuous. The result still holds in that case (the derivative satisfies [Darboux property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))).